# Get time (with local server's timezone), after a date_default_timezone_set call

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

- When calling just this line:

  ```
  <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>
  ```

  it returns the date/time **with the local server timezone**.  (Given that nothing is specified in php.ini and [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) hasn't been called before). That's what I want.
- Now let's assume I'm coding a PHP plugin to a CMS, and that this CMS redefines the default-time-zone:

  ```
  <?php 
  // CMS code by a third-party
  // ...
  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
  // ...
  // CMS code

  // MY PLUGIN
  echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
  // MY PLUGIN
  ```

  In the last line, the `date(...)` is affected by the previous `date_default_timezone_set` call (from the CMS code).

**Question: how to get the date/time with local server timezone, after a `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` has been called?** and *without* hardcoding the server timezone like this `$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));`

Comment: Can you run external commands to the OS? You could use [one of them](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) to call the system date ..

Comment: @wcomnisky preferably not, I just want to recover the same state than before the CMS's call to `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`